# How to pass image dynamically in modal

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I have a modal that is displaying data of product dynamically.
I managed to get this working via Jquery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
    $('#show').modal('show');
    $('#i').text($(this).data('id'));
    $('#ti').text($(this).data('name'));
    $('#by').text($(this).data('description'));
    $('#pr').text($(this).data('price'));
    // $('#im').text($(this).data('image'));

    $('#image').html($(this).data('image') );
    $('.modal-title').text('Show Post');
});
```

The only problem I am unable to pass images by passing #image id into view. It looks like this:

```
  <img class="first_img" src=" " alt=""/>
```

If I pass  into src="", I get to see image URL but no image is showing.

The modal activation button looks like this:

```
<a href="#" class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm"  data-id="{{$product->id}}"
                    data-name="{{$product->name}}" data-description="{{$product->description}}" data-price="{{$product->price}}"

                    data-image="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->images->first()->full) }}"  >
                    <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
 </a>
```

All textual data like $product->id, $product->name are being passed dynamically ok.
The only issue I don't know how to pass the image dynamically.

Here is HTML of the modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" title="modal" id="show" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="quickview" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="close btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="quickview_body">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-5">
                            <div class="quickview_pro_img">


                                <img class="first_img" src="" id="image" alt=""/>

                                <img class="hover_img" src="{{ asset('storage/'.$product->images->random()->full) }}" alt="">
                                <!-- Product Badge -->
                                <div class="product_badge">
                                    <span class="badge-new">New</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-7">
                            <div class="quickview_pro_des">
                                <h4 class="data"></h4>
                                <b id="ti"/>


                                <div class="top_seller_product_rating mb-15">
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                                </div>
                                <h5 class="price">{{config('settings.currency_symbol')}} <b id="pr"/></span></h5>
                                {{--description--}}
                                <p><b id="by"/></p>

                                <a href="{{ route('product.show', $product->name) }}">View Full Product Details</a>
                            </div>
                            <!-- Add to Cart Form -->
                            <form class="cart" method="post">

                                <button type="submit" name="addtocart" value="5" class="cart-submit">Add to
                                    cart</button>
                                <a href="" type="" value="5" class="cart-submit">Product Details</a>

                                <!-- Wishlist -->
                                <div class="modal_pro_wishlist">
                                    <a href="wishlist.html"><i class="icofont-heart"></i></a>
                                </div>
                                <!-- Compare -->
                                <div class="modal_pro_compare">
                                    <a href="compare.html"><i class="icofont-exchange"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                            <!-- Share -->
                            <div class="share_wf mt-30">
                                <p>Share with friends</p>
                                <div class="_icon">
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-pinterest" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can do this?

Comment: Is #image a container or the <img id="image"> element itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm 99% sure you're not passing along the correct information.

What is the value of this: `asset('storage/'.$product->images->first()->full)`

Its most likely a file path.
If so, instead of using

```
$('#image').html($(this).data('image') );
```

use

```
$('#image').attr("src",$(this).data('image'));
```

If `asset('storage/'.$product->images->first()->full)` returns something like `<img src="pathToImage.jpg">` then your code should work.

---

Also, a side note, if you're using `$(this)` more than once, store it in a variable so it becomes faster to access when you call it. You'll reduce the overhead of jQuery converting `this` into a jQuery object every time.

Something like

```
$(document).on('click', '.show-modal', function() {
    var t = $(this);
    $('#show').modal('show');
    $('#i').text(t.data('id'));
    $('#ti').text(t.data('name'));
    $('#by').text(t.data('description'));
    $('#pr').text(t.data('price'));

    $('#image').attr("src",$(this).data('image'));
    $('.modal-title').text('Show Post');
});
```

Comment: Ok, and how do I put this id into scr=" " in view?

Comment: @PinPiguin Use jQuery's .attr() method like I suggested in my answer. I would need to see the HTML of your modal just to make sure of something.

Comment: see above. I need to make the image available in <img class="first_img" src="<b id='image'/> " alt=""/>

Comment: I moved your HTML out of the answer and into your question where it belongs. 

I see you're using `<img class="first_img" src="" id="image" alt=""/>` so my answer should be correct.

You can use `$('#image').attr("src",$(this).data('image'));` to change the source of the image.